# What do the module walls look like on the ISS?

Tags: iss, spacecraft-development, structural-design

I know they are about 10cm thick and act like a whipple shield. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20120002584
It should be two layers of aluminum. But when I look at the photos from the inside, the walls look black.
[image: destiny module]

Is there anything else in the walls? For example cooling (tubes with cooling liquid), some sensors, distributions and so on? How "functional" are the walls? Or is it just several layers of different materials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've probably seen, the inner walls of the ISS modules are almost totally obscured by racks and other equipment.

The "barest" modules are the Multi-Purpose Logistics Modules (MPLMs), which are constructed in the same manner as the other modules of the ISS but were left mostly empty to serve in their role as cargo carriers. MPLM-1 was actually left at the ISS to become a permanent module.

When the MPLMs were being loaded and unloaded on the ground at KSC, there are some pictures that show the inner walls fairly well (see above the workers' heads for example). Here are a couple.

[image]

[image]

Source: images.nasa.gov (search for "mplm at ksc")

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Of course I know that the walls are covered with seagulls and equipment. I was talking about the construction of the 10 cm (really just the wall itself). But the other pictures of the insides of the modules are also useful to me.

Comment: Seagulls? Terribly messy in micro-g

Comment: @SaturnV ... "seagulls"? What are seagulls?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "racks". Google translator is to blame.